# how to pass variable from function using Python

Tags: python, function

I need to pass the seed inside the function to the main to do other things, but the seed will only show empty.

```
seed = {}
def search (seed):
    seed = 0
    print (seed)

search(seed)
print (seed)
```

the 1st `print (seed) >>>'0'`

but the second `print (seed)` will only show `>>>{}`

I know 0 is a int, but even i change to string type like "hello" it will still have the same result. Please help

Comment: you mean returning a value from the funtion?, anyway take a look over scopes in python.

Comment: You can use a `return seed` at the end of your function and change the `search(seed)` in your main by `seed = search(seed)`

Comment: by this way you redecalre `seed` in `local visibility` in function, but extern `seed` no changed. Try to use `seed[0] = 0`

Comment: Why do you test if `abc` is `123`, when you've just set it on the line above?  The `else` suite will _never_ execute.  Why do you replace your dictionary with a `0` (or a string like `'hello'`, for that matter)?  What do you want out of this code --- a dictionary, an integer, or a string?  What are you _trying_ to do?

Comment: it is just an example code, the important part is to pass out the seed value either digit or string, the problem now is i cannot pass out the seeds value, it shows 0, This is my question, just ignore about the abc or watever else. Tq

Comment: How can we tell which lines of code we're supposed to ignore, and which are actually part of your problem?  Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve], without all the "whatever else".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are declaring the `seed` variable as an *empty list* and inside the `search` method using it to assign `integer` values. This doesn't throw an `exception` as `seed` variable inside the `search` method is of *[local scope](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html)*. But you may want to look into the usage of `seed` variable. Whether you need it to be a `integer` or a `list`. Not both.
2. If you need the `seed` value in the *main* method, all you need to do is return the variable `seed` from the `search` method.

Like this:

```
def search (seed):
    abc = 123
    if abc == 123:
        # do something with *seed*
        return seed
    else:
        print ("why")

seed = search(seed)
print (seed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Return value from function and assign to a var.

```
seed = {}

def search (seed):
    abc = 123
    if abc == 123:
        seed = 0
        print (seed)
        return seed
    else:
        print ("why")

seed = search(seed)
print (seed)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function, reassigning `seed` inside the scope of the function recreate a new var.

So you need to take `seed` from global vars.

Try this:

```
seed = {}

def search ():
    global seed
    abc = 123
    if abc == 123:
        seed = 0
        print (seed)
        return seed
    else:
        print ("why")

 seed = search(seed)
 print (seed)
```

Answer (score 0):

By assigning *seed* in your function, you create a new local *seed* variable valid only within the function scope.

Check it ou - function *id* gives reference to variable:

```
In [95]: seed = {}

In [96]: id(seed)
Out[96]: 83506720

In [97]: foo(seed)
83506720
18955368

In [98]: id(seed)
Out[98]: 83506720
```

You may:

- Return value and assign it outside function
- Value of mutable variable may be changed by a function (assignment does not change value - it creates a new variable

  In [115]: def foo(seed, key, val):
      seed[key] = val
     .....:

  In [116]: seed = {}

  In [117]: foo(seed, 'value', 1)

  In [118]: seed
  Out[118]: {'value': 1}
- You may use *global* qualifier (terrible)

Answer (score 0):

```
seed={}
abc="seed"
seed[abc]={}

def getseed(seed):
    seed[abc]={0}

getseed(seed)
print (seed["seed"])

>>>'0'
```